# ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS patterns not picking up external files with numbers in the name

Tags: accurev

ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS is not filtering out files that look like this:

lib/junit/junit/4.10
or
lib/.cache/m2e/0.12.1/xxxx

I've tried these and none seem to pick up these files:

*/lib/* lib/* lib/** */lib/** **/lib/**

It says in the doc that the wildcard gets all characters including path separators. The problem seems to be specifically with files and directories that have a number or underscore in the name. Other files are getting filtered out.

Any suggestions for a pattern that will work?

The problem is happening in the External search view

Answer (score 0):

Is the lib directory an external file?  Meaning does it have a status of external in your accurev workspace?

If this directory is not external, the ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS environment variable will not hide the content from the AccuRev GUI.

Example:

c:\wspaces\test>ls

lib            src            test-src

c:\wspaces\test>accurev files

.\test-src           src\1 (1454\1) (backed)

.\src                src\1 (2\1) (backed)

c:\wspaces\test>set | grep IGNORE

ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS=lib

Comment: I should have said: I am using the External view to see External files. So that's where I'm seeing the problem.

Comment: Yes, but where are the external files?  What is the output from the following command: 'accurev stat lib'

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry, I get it now. lib is *not* external, so I guess that's my problem. The files within that I want to filter are external. Too bad if I can't filter them.

Comment: Well, you can.  Is the folder that contains these files external?  If so, you can define that folder to ignore.  Or, use an extension.  example, if all the files were .o files, you can ignore all *.o files.

Comment: Generally, the folders are not external. Yes, I'll play around with different patterns and see if I can get rid of them some other way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Within the **lib** folder, create a file named **.acignore**. This will allow you to create ignore rules specific to that folder. For example, if I want to ignore .o and .class files in that directory, the contents of **.acignore** would be:

```
*.o
*.class
```